# NGINX Ingress controller only returns "/" for Path in /metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I'm new with Kubernetes and Ingresses and so on but here is the deal. I have an issue I'm trying to solve for some time. I have a Kubernetes Cluster with 4 running servers (backend). I usually close or open new ones, change names, endpoints and so on to play with them and the cluster.

The issue is the following, in my Kubernetes Cluster I also have an Nginx Ingress Controller, Prometheus and Grafana.

When I try to read http requests (in Prometheus with PromQL), I can never read the path of an request. All the metrics are ok but the path is always "/" and this is not true because some servers have a path like /api/something and so on.

I've tried several approaches and I cannot find the path. The kubectl logs is showing the path but the /metrics and the Prometheus only shows "/". It might be a simple thing, or an ordinary one but I could not find a way to display the full path of an request and I really need that. Thank you and sorry if my issue is banal or very easy to solve but I could not find a way to do it.

Thank you so much!

I tried to search online and in the official documentation for an answer but I could not find one. I found that if I manually type the endpoints paths, it will work but if I have dynamically servers it won't work for me as they always change.